# Auto populate other fields in a form from database based on selection in combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have a requirement where a data in a table has to be entered and it has to be checked. I am done with the entry of new records. I am trying to do the check data part. I could form a combo box where the data from database is populated. I want other fields(fields from database) on the form to be populated based on the selection in the combo box so that the values can be checked and corrected if any errors are present. Please help me as I am very new to Access.

Answer (score 1):

Use the wizards to create a form based on your table. Next use the wizards to add a combobox and select "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combobox" in the options for your combo.

[image: combo]

Comment: Thank you Remou. The table that I am working on already has data. I created a form already based on it.Now when I am trying to create form it doesn't provide me the option "Find a record on my form based on the value I select in my combo box". Is there any other way by which I can say to populate the field values from database by using form properties or VB code.

Comment: Add a combo box using the wizard. It will offer you the option if the form is based on a table or query. There are a dozen ways, this is the easiest by far.

Comment: I tried the option. The values are being displayed in the same combo box. I want them to updated in the next fields accordingly on the form. Ex: I have id, c_id,c_date,c_gender. When I select c_id then the other fields(c_id,c_date,c_gender) should be populated on the form. Then I should be able to check it and then update it if it is wrong.

Comment: I am afraid you are not setting this up correctly. Create a form based on a table so it has all the records in the table. Add a combobox using the wizard and select the option as illustrated above. You need only choose a unique ID and any other field that allows you to identify the record for the combobox. When you select a record from the combobox, the form will navigate to that record. You can see this by observing the navigation bar at the bottom of the form.

Comment: Thank You. I was able to set it up and get the values. But once I update a record that record remains as default in the id box. How can I make it empty once I update one record.

Comment: You can use the On Dirty event for the form to set the combobox to null. `Me.MyCombo=Null`